# Escape special characters in a text when text is either enclosed in double quotes or not

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a regex to escape a few special characters including double quote from the input.

input can be enclosed in double quotes and those should be not escaped.

Ex of input :

```
"te(st", te(st, te"st
```

expected outputs :

```
"te\(st", te\(st, te\"st
```

Code used :

```
String regex = "^\".*\"$";
    String value = "\"strin'g\"";
    Pattern SPECIAL_REGEX_CHARS = Pattern.compile("[()'"\\[\\]*]");

    if (Pattern.matches(regex, value)){
        String val = value.substring(1, value.length() -1);
        String replaceAll = SPECIAL_REGEX_CHARS.matcher(val).replaceAll("\\\\$0");
        replaceAll = "\""+replaceAll+"\"";
        System.out.println(replaceAll);
    }else {
        String replaceAll = SPECIAL_REGEX_CHARS.matcher(value).replaceAll("\\\\$0");
        System.out.println(replaceAll);
    }
```

1 - checking if the text is enclosed in double quotes. if yes, escape the special characters in the text that is enclosed in double quotes.

2 - else . escape special characters in the text.

any regex expression which can combine #1 and #2 ?

Regards,
Anil

Comment: It can be done with code using 1 regex. Still, it will require some lines of additional code.

Comment: Third line doesn't compile.

Comment: could you please share regex , using conditional regex ? i want to try it is better way. not sure if my approach is standard one.

Comment: try Pattern SPECIAL_REGEX_CHARS = Pattern.compile("[()\"'\\[\\]*]");

Comment: Wouldn't you want \ to be escaped as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Simple solution with one escaping regex only

You may use the `if (s.startsWith("\"") && s.endsWith("\""))` to check if a string has both leading and trailing `"`, and if it does, you can then trim out the leading and trailing `"` with `replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "")`, then escape using your escaping regex, and then add `"` back. Else, just escape the characters in your set.

```
String SPECIAL_REGEX_CHARS = "[()'\"\\[\\]*]";
String s = "\"te(st\""; // => "te\(st"
String result;
if (s.startsWith("\"") && s.endsWith("\"")) {
    result = "\"" + s.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "").replaceAll(SPECIAL_REGEX_CHARS, "\\\\$0") + "\"";
}
else {
    result = s.replaceAll(SPECIAL_REGEX_CHARS, "\\\\$0");
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

See another [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/uGulmy)

## Alternative solution with `appendReplacement` "callback"

Here is how I would do that with one regex using an alternation:

```
String SPECIAL_REGEX_CHARS = "[()'\"\\[\\]*]";
//String s = "\"te(st\""; // => "te\(st"
//String s = "te(st"; // => te\(st
String s = "te\"st"; // => te\"st
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?s)\"(.*)\"|(.*)").matcher(s);
if (m.matches()) {
    if (m.group(1) == null) { // we have no quotes around
        m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(2).replaceAll(SPECIAL_REGEX_CHARS, "\\\\\\\\$0"));
    }
    else {
        m.appendReplacement(result, "\"" + m.group(1).replaceAll(SPECIAL_REGEX_CHARS, "\\\\\\\\$0") + "\"");
    }
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/tXdKXt)

Main points:

- The [`Matcher#addReplacement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) with [`Matcher#appendTail()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail(java.lang.StringBuffer)) allow manipulating groups.
- Using `(?s)\"(.*)\"|(.*)` regex with 2 alternative branches: `".*"` matching a string starting with `"` and ending with `"` (note that `(?s)` is a DOTALL inline modifier allowing matching strings with newline sequences) or a `.*` alternative just matching all other strings.
- If the 1st alternative is matched, we just replace the selected special characters in the first capture group, and then add the `"` on both ends.
- If the second alternative is matched, just add the escaping symbol in the whole Group 2.
- To replace with a literal backslash, you need `\\\\\\\\` in the replacement pattern.

Comment: You know, "simplified" may mean different things for different people :) I think this is already simple taking into account your requirements. If anything is unclear, please ask.

Comment: I have added a "simpler" solution with minimal regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [negative lookbehind and lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
System.out.println(value.replaceAll("([()'\\[\\]*]|(?<!^)\"(?!$))", "\\\\$0"));
```

This is essentially saying: escape anything in character class `[()'\[\]*]`, or any `"` not preceded by beginning-of-string or followed by end-of-string.

The only catch is that a leading and trailing quote will be ignored regardless of whether it has a corresponding quote at the other end. If that's a problem, you can chain these replacements to escape an unmatched leading or trailing quote:

```
.replaceAll("^\".*[^\"]$", "\\\\$0")
.replaceAll("(^[^\"].*)(\"$)", "$1\\\\$2")
```

Comment: The problems with lookaround approach is that this way, one cannot check if the input has `"` both at the start *and* end  of the string.

Comment: @AnilDasari, I'm getting `"\(te\"st"`. Were you expecting something else?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that depends on how particular he is on checking for matching quotes. For all I know, it may not possible for this input to have unmatched quotes.

Comment: Ok, anyway, I believe that checking if a string starts or ends with a double quote, we do not really need a regex.